# Converting an input of space delimited integers to a list

Tags: python, beginner, homework

```
tablou = input("Enter values delimited by space: ")
b = tablou.split()

t = [] # initial  list with int() contents
for l in b:
    r = int(l)
    t.append(r)
```

I have to do multiple assignments which require working with lists of integers/floats.  Above is what I'm using for converting a string to a proper list of integers.  I was wondering if there's any way to optimize the code in a such way that it won't need to use memory to keep `tablou`, `b` and the final list.  I would be actually working with `t`

I'm not sure if I used the right terms to describe the issue, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Releasing memory

If you assign `None` to your variables, their contents is lost and the memory will (eventually) be reclaimed.

```
tablou = input("Enter values delimited by space: ")

b = tablou.split()
tablou = None

t = [] # initial  list with int() contents

for l in b:
    r = int(l)
    t.append(r)
b = None
l = None
r = None
```

### Forgetting the variables

The variables `tablou`, `l`, `b`, and `r` will still exist; they will just contain the value `None`.  If you accidentally use the variable `tablou` again, you won't get a `NameError: name 'tablou' is not defined`, although you may get an error stating the operation cannot be performed on the value `None`.

Better would be to delete the variables when they are no longer needed:

```
del tablou
del l, b, r
```

After deleting the variables, it is an error to refer to them again, without first storing a value under that name.

### List Comprehension

Repeatedly appending values to a list is an expensive operation.  It is usually faster to create the list using "list comprehension".

First, note that instead of this ...

```
t = []

for l in b:
    r = int(l)
    t.append(r)
```

... you could write this, eliminating the `r` variable:

```
t = []

for l in b:
    t.append(int(l))
```

Then, you can replace the list creation, loop, append with the following:

```
t = [ int(l) for l in b ]
```

This does the same thing as the former code, but without the repeated `append` call.  As a bonus, the list comprehension variable, `l` does not escape into the local scope; there is no need to `del l`.

### Mapping

Applying the same operation to every element of a list is called a "mapping", and Python comes with a built in function `map()` to do just that.

In your specific case, you are calling `int( )` on every item in the list `b`, so instead of:

```
t = [ int(l) for l in b ]
```

you could write:

```
t = list(map(int, b))
```

**Advance topic**: The `map()` function actually returns an iterator, rather than a list.  In many cases, you can avoid the call to `list()`, which iterates over all the items the iterator can produce and builds a list of out them, and simply use the returned iterator directly.

### One-liner

You can reduce your code to one line, removing all temporary variables, using nested calls:

```
t = list(map(int, input("Enter values delimited by space: ").split()))
```

I don't recommend it, however.  It does not result in easy-to-understand code.  It is better to separate "user input" from "processing".

### Variable Names

`t`, `r`, `l` and `b` are horrible variable names.  Name the variables with longer, descriptive names.